# How to indent lists but not headings in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

As the question says: I would like to indent the lists using org-indent-mode (or any other option) but not the headings. The org-indent-mode produces

```
* heading 1
  * heading 2
  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxx
    - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxx
```

I would like to have

```
* heading 1
** heading 2
- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx
  - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxx
```

Comment: There is a `org-indent-mode-turns-on-hiding-stars` variable you might be interested in.

Comment: I tried, but it seems it just shows the starts. The main issue is not showing or not the starts, but aligning only in the lists, not in the heading.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing. Every solution I tried for indenting seems to insert hard wraps (e.g. `fill region`, `M-q`). The only one that inserts soft wraps is `org-indent-mode`, but I also want it only for the lists.